# Python. Проблема с кодировкой при чтении .json файла (cp1251 и UTF-8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, utf-8, кодировка

```
# some_data.json:

    # Кусок проблемной части кода:
    {
                "result": [
                {
                      "answers": {
                            "A": "Ф. Фукуяме",
                            "B": "А. Камю",
                            "C": "Ф. Ницше",
                            "D": "Э. Кассиреру",
                            "E": "В. Франклу"
                      },
                },
                {
                      "question": "Строгий нравственный закон И.  Канта носит 
                                   название:",
                }
          ]
    }
```

Распарсив данные с **.docx** word документа, я записал их в **.json** файл **some_data.json**. При попытке попытке прочитать данные с **some_data.json** я получаю в кривую кодировку в некоторых местах одного типа "\xa0", который как я понял означает пробел

```
    with open('some_data.json', encoding='utf8') as f:
        some = json.load(f)
    for item in some:
        print(f"{item}\n")

# Выполнение программы:

{
     'index': '13',
     'question': 'Определение человека как символического животного принадлежит:',
     'answers': {
                'A': 'Ф. Фукуяме',
                'B': 'А.\xa0Камю',
                'C': 'Ф.\xa0Ницше',
                'D': 'Э. Кассиреру',
                'E': 'В. Франклу'},
     'right_answer': 'D'
},
{
     'index': '19',
     'question': 'Строгий нравственный закон И.\xa0 Канта носит название:',
     'answers': {
                'A': 'синтетическое суждение',
                'B': 'трансцендентный императив',
                'C': 'категорический императив',
                'D': 'гипотетический принцип', 
                'E': 'антиномия'
      },
     'right_answer': 'C'
}
```

Замечу, что, когда вывожу **без** `encoding='utf8'`, `print(f)` дает

```
with open('some_data.json') as f:
print(f)

>>> <_io.TextIOWrapper name='delete.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1251'>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993612/python-removing-xa0-from-string

Comment: Это не кривая кодировка и это обозначение **неразрывного** пробела. Правильнее всего будет ничего не трогать и оставить как есть, потому что неразрывный пробел — важный типографский символ